# How to convert Address type of Barcode.CONTACT_INFO To String Type in Android?

Tags: java, android, computer-vision

I am using implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:19.0.0' library for scanning bar code, when it scan contactinfo QR code it gives dummy value. Address, URL, Email and Phone give dummy value, it did not convert in String Value.

```
@Override
public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<Barcode> detections) {
    final SparseArray<Barcode> barcodes = detections.getDetectedItems();
    if (barcodes.size() != 0) {

        for (int index = 0; index < barcodes.size(); index++) {
            Barcode code = barcodes.valueAt(index);
            int type = barcodes.valueAt(index).valueFormat;
            switch (type) {
                case Barcode.CONTACT_INFO:
                    String name = code.contactInfo.name.formattedName;
                    String title = code.contactInfo.title;
                    String organization = code.contactInfo.organization;
                    String address = code.contactInfo.addresses.toString();
                    String phone = code.contactInfo.phones.toString();
                    String emails = code.contactInfo.emails.toString();
                    String urls = code.contactInfo.urls.toString();

                    break;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you execute this?

Comment: [com.google.android.gms.vission.barcode.Barcode$Phone@4e1dd42]
[com.google.android.gms.vission.barcode.Barcode$Email@8a1853]
[com.google.android.gms.vission.barcode.Barcode$Address@61878d]

it gives the values like this

Comment: Name, Title and organization these values are correct but phone, email and Address
create problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this documentation.

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/vision/barcode/Barcode.ContactInfo

```
public Address[] addresses  
public Email[]   emails
public Phone[]   phones 
public String[]  urls
```

These values are array, so cannot use toString() function.

You can check the classes  (Address, Email and Phone) to get corresponding value from this documentation.

For example, to get first phone number,

```
Barcode.Phone[] phones = code.contactInfo.phones;
if (phones.length > 1) {
    Barcode.Phone phone = phones[0];
    String phoneNumber = phone.number;
}
```

Hope to be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can get contact information from either a bar code or QR code.

```
                        String mName ="", mTitle ="", mOrganization="";
                        String mAddress = "", mPhone = "", mEmail = "", mUrl ="";

                        mName = code.contactInfo.name.formattedName;
                        mTitle = code.contactInfo.title;
                        mOrganization = code.contactInfo.organization;
                       
                        Barcode.Address[] addresses = code.contactInfo.addresses;
                        if (addresses.length >= 1) {
                            Barcode.Address address = addresses[0];
                            mAddress = address.addressLines[0];
                        }

                        Barcode.Phone[] phones = code.contactInfo.phones;
                        if (phones.length >=1) {
                            Barcode.Phone phone = phones[0];
                            mPhone = phone.number;
                        }

                        Barcode.Email[] emails  = code.contactInfo.emails;
                        if (emails.length >= 1) {
                            Barcode.Email email = emails[0];
                            mEmail = email.address;
                        }


                        String[] urls  = code.contactInfo.urls;
                        if (urls.length >= 1) {
                            mUrl = urls[0];
                            
                        }

                        String contact_info = mName+"\n"+mTitle+"\n"+mOrganization+"\n"+mAddress+"\n"+
                                mPhone+"\n"+mEmail+"\n"+mUrl;
```